# Which no sql db to be used when deploying an application (spring boot) to google app engine?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, google-app-engine

planning to develop a spring boot application and deploy to google app engine, some of the posts mentioned google app engine does not support mongoDB and we need to use Google datastore. 
Like mongo, can we operations and create on the fly tables in google datasource ?

Answer (score 0):

App Engine has [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/) database. Although it is not the only option.

To create entities [check this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-models). In Java you just need to create new Entity objects, and then you are ready to store them using "put". The "table" is created automatically. Note: They call object types "Kind", not "table".